# Random image using javascript, not reloading image from cache

Tags: image, random, slideshow

Im working on DotNetNuke BTBRandomImage module and this a custumization of the module to randomly change images on a timer based event.

This has been implemented using javascript. But the problem is evertime when the "src" of image is changed it requests the image again from the server. This increases the number of http requests towards the server.

Is there any way where i can reduce these request,and why are the same images getting downloaded again?

Thanks in advance,

Pooja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't change the src, just load the images and hide/show/move them into the dom

Answer (score 0):

if the name of the image is changing between posts there is no way to prevent loading from the server...